# Quadratic GLM in R with interactions?

Tags: r, glm, quadratic

So I have a question of utilizing quadratic (second order) predictors with GLMs in R. Basically I have three predictor variables (x, y, z) and a response variable (let's call it ozone). 
X, Y, and Z are not pquadratic predictors yet so I square them 
X2<- x^2 (same for y and z)

Now I understand that if I wanted to model ozone based off of these predictor variables I would use the poly() or polym() function

However, when it comes to using interaction terms between these three variables...that's where I get lost. For example, if i wanted to model the interaction between the quadratic predictors of X and Y I believe I would be typing in something like this

ozone<- x+ x2 + y+y2+ x*y +x2*y + x*y2 + x2*y2 + x*y (I hope this is right)

My question is, is there an easier way of inputting this (with three terms that's a lot of typing). My other question is why does the quadratic predictor flip signs in the coefficients? When I just run the predictor variable X the coefficient is positive but when I use a quadratic predictor the coefficient almost always ends up being negative.

Comment: `(poly(x, 2) + poly(y, 2))^2` or `(poly(x, 2)*poly(y, 2))`

Comment: It might be worthwhile to think a bit on exactly what you mean by "interaction" here.

Comment: am i thinking of interactions wrong?

Comment: You have continuous predictor variables. Typically when talking about interactions, at least one predictor is assumed to be categorical, so we can talk about different trends or slopes per category.

Comment: I don't think that's correct @HongOoi. You can have an interaction between two continuous variables. In this case, it would mean that the relationship between `x` and `Ozone` varies for different values of `y` and the relationship between `y` and `Ozone` varies for different values of `x`.

Comment: @eipi10 yes, that's technically correct. But typically when we want to fit that kind of relationship, we call it a _surface_ rather than an _interaction_ (eg response surfaces, smooth surfaces). OP's use of the word "interaction", as well as using polynomials and multiplying them together, suggests a possible misunderstanding.

Comment: It depends who "we" is. I, like @eipi10, would refer to the interactions between continuous predictors without changing terminologies.  I'd suggest that the OP might be better off with `poly(x,y,z,degree=n)` ... where `n` might be up to 6 (!).  But what model the OP *should* fit is heading into CrossValidated territory ...

Comment: @BenBolker ...... as in the author behind the ecological application with R?!

Comment: Yes, *that* @BenBolker.

Comment: I would suggest that @user20650 should post their solution as an answer, and a follow-up question about whether this is the a good *statistical* solution could be asked by OP on [CrossValided](http://stats.stackexchange.com) (with a link to this question) ... (hopefully with a little more context about the actual scientific problem)